# How to get data to Dropdownlist from database in html view

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating an web page in which have a `Dropdownlist`. I have to retrieve data for the drop_down_list from the database. Is there any way to get data from the database to the html view my html code:

`<select name="drop down"><option value="1">@test.list[i]</option></select>`

I got the database value to the list variable but I don't know how to pass the data to the html view. Please help me in this issue.Thanks

Comment: use `@Html.DropdownListFor()`

Comment: without using razor code can i get data ?

Comment: in this where i need to pass the data  
use @Html.DropdownListFor(HERE?) ....?

Comment: yes that's where you need to pass it

Answer (score 2):

You need to create Select List of Items :

**Your Action with List of Items in View Bag :**

```
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
 List<SelectListItem> Items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        CustReportName.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "List1", Value = "1", Selected = false });
        CustReportName.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "List2", Value = "2", Selected = true });
        ViewBag.ListItems = Items;
return View("ViewName");
}
```

**For Multiple values from database table:**

```
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ItemsList = from item in YourTableObject
select new SelectListItem
{
Value = Convert.ToString(item.Id),
Text = item.ItemName
};
ViewBag.ListItems = new SelectList(ItemsList, "Value", "Text");
return View("ViewName");
}
```

**Your DropdownList On view :**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ItemId, new SelectList(ViewBag.ItemList, "Value", "Text", 0), "-Select Item-", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ItemId" })
```

**Cheers !!**

Comment: i need to get more than 300 data for the dropdown list ? is the code work for that ?@laxman gite

Comment: Yah definitly I have updated my code for multiple values from database table

Comment: Please accept this ans if your work is done. do let me know if you have any other question for that.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a simple two step process:

Step1 :Action method code

```
public ActionResult Index()  
{
  ViewBag.users = db.users.ToList();
}
```

Step2: cshtml code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.someId, new SelectList(ViewBag.users, "userId", "userName"), "Select users")
```

Note: with this, you can bind n number of data from the database to dropdownlist

Hope it was useful

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: what is db in the action result @karthik

Comment: its is just  your application  dbcontext instance , kindly refer this for official info:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx

Thanks