# How to get value from dropdownlist and assign to an object in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Am very new to MVC. Am developing a small tool for my project. I want to get the selected value from the drop down list and assign to an object to use further. My code looks like this.

**VIEW:**

```
    @model SolutionMasterDataRepl.Models.ReplDataModel

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Solution Master";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.btn-toggle').click(function () {
                $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('active');
                if ($(this).find('.btn-primary').size() > 0) {
                    $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-primary');
                }
                if ($(this).find('.btn-danger').size() > 0) {
                    $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-danger');
                }
                if ($(this).find('.btn-success').size() > 0) {
                    $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-success');
                }
                if ($(this).find('.btn-info').size() > 0) {
                    $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-info');
                }
                $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-default');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .form-horizontal{
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 50%
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Data REPL</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="selectReplServer" class="col-lg-4">Select REPL Server</label>
                <div class="col-lg-offset-4">
                    <select class="form-control" id="replServer" style="width: 200px">
                        <option>PTW01REPLAP001</option>                                            
                    </select>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedReplDatabase, Model.ReplDatabase, "Select REPL Server")
                </div>                
            </div>
```

**MODEL:**

```
    public class ReplDataModel
  {
    public SelectList ReplDatabase { get; set; }
    public string SelectedReplDatabase { get; set; }
  }
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    string replDatabase = string.Empty;
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetReplDatabase(ReplDataModel model)
    {
      replDatabase = model.SelectedReplDatabase;
      return View(model);
    }
  }
```

Am getting null reference exception here:
`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedReplDatabase, Model.ReplDatabase, "Select REPL Server"`)
Can you people help me to sort out the error and suggest better way of assign the values from dropdownlist.

Comment: You are not setting value for Model and Model.ReplDatabase in controller action.

Comment: Check this ans : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429163/how-to-get-data-to-dropdownlist-from-database-in-html-view/44430272#44430272

Comment: Your not passing a model to your view so `Model.ReplDatabase` is `null`. You need to initialize a new instance of `ReplDataModel`, populate the `ReplDatabase` property and return it to the view (and you also need to repopulate it in the POST method. but what are you trying to do here. A new controller is initialized each call so as soon as you return the view in the POST method the value of `replDatabase` is lost

Comment: Thank You all..It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    string replDatabase = string.Empty;
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      ReplDataModel Model = new ReplDataModel();
      return View(Model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetReplDatabase(ReplDataModel model)
    {
      replDatabase = model.SelectedReplDatabase;
      return View(model);
    }
  }
```

You are not passing Model value in Get method and check also replDatabase in post method. you are not assign anything.

Comment: Mention Not... :)